# Drive space hungry NoSQL's databases

Tags: mysql, mongodb, couchdb, nosql

I've tested NoSQL databases like CouchDB, MongoDB and Cassandra and observed tendence to absorbing very large amount of drive space relative to inserted key-value pairs. 
When comparing CouchDB and MySQL schemaless databases CouchDB is consuming much more drive space than MySQL. 
I know about that key-value DBs by default are versioning and have long uuid and need key optimalisation - the comparison was between about 15 mln rows in MySQL and 1-5 mln documents listed NoSQL DB's.

**My question is** : Is there any NoSQL with good compaction / compression of data?
So that I can have NoSQL database with a size closer to 5GB than 50GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has a "database repair" function that also performs a compaction. However, such a compaction is not going to happen while the DB is running.

But if DB space is a serious issue, then try setting up a MongoDB master/slave pair. As the data needs compaction, run the repair on the slave, allow it to "catch up" and then switch them over. You can now safely compact the master instead.

But I have to echo *jbellis*'s comment: you will probably need more space and most of these products are making the assumption that disk space is (relatively) cheap. If disk space is really tight, then you'll find that MongoDB is reasonably sized, but it's going to have a difficult time competing with tabular CSV data.

Think of it this way, **what's more space efficient**?

- a CSV file with a million lines
- that same data formatted in JSON

Obviously the JSON is going to be longer b/c you're repeating the field names every time. The only exception here is a CSV file with like 100 columns of which only a few are filled for each row. (but that's probably not your data)

Comment: That's true, if you use long field names you need more disk space when using Mongodb. And Mongodb preallocates files of 2 gigabyte.

Comment: Yes, CouchDB has "compact" option too witch after test reduce db size several times (Cassandra do it like "in background" because of better organized bulk writes).

Comment: Piggy backing on this, if it's a problem with 1 node having enough disk space, try something like HBase or Cassandra it's very easy to add more data storage (and processing power!) simply by adding more nodes. I don't know how MongoDB/CouchDB are structured, so I don't know if you can easily and simply do the same thing with them.

Comment: MongoDB also allows for "horizontal" scaling via sharding.

Answer (score 4):

Disk space is about the cheapest resource today, so if you can trade it for less seeks or less CPU used it is a good trade to make.  That is what Cassandra does.

Comment: Magnetic disk space yes, but not SSD space, which is what you'll want a high performance DB stored on anyway. Seeks on the other hand are nearly free on SSDs. Furthermore, efficiently packing data into pages on disk means potentially much more effective caching at the page buffer layer within the DB, another win.

Comment: magnetic vs ssd is not one-size-fits all; if your hot data set fits into ram (very common!) then ssd is just flushing money down the drain.  for less predictable workloads you do see Cassandra deployed on SSDs, where its avoidance of seeks on writes is a big win for (non) write amplification.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the key. CouchDB stores its data in a b-tree. UUID - keys are the cause the that you need a large amount of disk space. B-tree stores data compact by nature exept UUID's. Try to find a key which is more confortable for a b-tree.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking the "file length" or the actual allocation size?

Many databases sparsely allocate file structures and their "length" is much larger than their on-disk size.

Comment: I check that too, that file buffer isn't so big so I not even consider that in db like 15 mln documents (even if it will be few GB). I think this "space hungry" is weekness of shemaless db's but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [AceBase](https://github.com/appy-one/acebase), which is also a NoSQL database engine. It caches the key names in your objects in a "Key Index Table" and stores references to those items with your objects. On top of this, it stores the data in a binary format to further reduce the space used.

So, instead of storing an object like `{"name": "Ewout Stortenbeker", "country": "The Netherlands" }`, it adds the used keys `name` and `country` to its KIT: `0:name,1:country` and then stores the object like `0:Ewout Stortenbeker,1:The Netherlands` (both in binary form).

If you'd add 10 million user records like this, the key names `name` and `country` will only be stored once, and their index in the KIT used for all those records. Besides saving space, this also greatly improves performance.